# I am using agora Client API in my web, but it's not returning a list of users list

Tags: laravel, agora

I am following this link to integrate Agora Chat SDK using Client API
https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/client-api/messages/retrieve-messages?platform=web
but it's not returning a list. I have created 2 users and all is working fine like both users can chat but we refresh the page the agora isn't returning a chat list.

Comment: Can you add some code what have you done and tried so far?

Comment: @thefallen the above issue is fixed by agora support basically they have suggested to add toLowerCase() with username while connection opening, and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now after contact agora support they told me to add toLowerCase() with the user in open connection call E.g.

```
WebIM.conn.open(
{
      user: username.toLowerCase(),
      agoraToken: token,
});
```

Comment: mark then as correct!

Answer (score 1):

There is a small tip in doc:
[Retrieve a list of conversations from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZv6w.png)

As I know, they intend to be compatible with mixed upper-case issues